# Remove dates from rss

Tags: feeds

can someone help me on how to remove or manually edit the post dates displayed on my drupal feeds? No I am not using views to create it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your content type you feed and click on "Manage Display". There you have different possibilities to change the way how your content looks in different view modes. You probably need to activate the view mode for RSS Feeds to change anything.